# Bitmap from Byte array shift

Tags: c#, bitmap, streaming, byte, marshalling

I'm trying to create Bitmap from byte array using this code:

```
var b = new Bitmap(pervoe, vtoroe, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
ColorPalette ncp = b.Palette;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    ncp.Entries[i] = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i);

b.Palette = ncp;

var BoundsRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

BitmapData bmpData = b.LockBits(BoundsRect,ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,b.PixelFormat);

IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

int bytes = (bmpData.Stride)*(b.Height);
        var rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
// filling values

Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

b.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return b;
```

the problem is that when I get the output image each row starting from the first is shifted to the right so the whole image doesnt look right .
The problem is not in the rgbValues - I've tried to use it with setPixel method and it works perfectly.
Any help with marshal class or what do I do to prevent that shifting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are showing looks fine and should work as intended. The problem is most likely related to how you've implemented the `// filling values` part. My guess is that the width of your image is such that `bmpData.Stride != b.Width` (and thus `bytes != Width * Height`) but you do not account for it and fill the first `Width * Height` bytes of the `rgbValues` array.

For optimilization purposes, the `Bitmap` implementation may choose to add padding bytes to each row of image data that are not actually part of the image. If it does so, you should account for this and write your image data to the first `Width` bytes of each row, where each rows starts at index `rowIndex * BitmapData.Stride`.

You should thus fill your buffer along the lines of:

```
for (int row = 0; row < b.Height; ++row)
{
    int rowStart = row * bmpData.Stride;
    for (int column = 0; column < b.Width; ++column)
    {
        rgbValues[rowStart + column] = GetColorForPixel(column, row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alooooooottt!!! that was the peculiarity I didn't know about.everything works fine now!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if you deem it correct :-)

Comment: This also helped me.  I knew about the "rounding to the nearest mod-4" that bitmaps do on width, but i did not know that the source data had to have padding in it to accomodate this.  That's ludicrous if i'm building from a byte stream.